# Access jQuery Component event in Angular6 component

Tags: jquery, angular6

I have a jQuery legacy component embedded inside Angular6. Have to re-use this. Is there a way I can trap a jQuery triggered event within my angular component? The only way I can get it to work is by passing in a callback function to the jQuery component. Any insights to make it work over the event mechanism?

```
<my-component (modelmodified)="modelChanged($event)"></my-component>

@Output () modelmodified: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any> ();
```

Internally in the legacy jQuery component if I throw the following event

```
$(document).trigger("model-modified", newModel);
```

Is there a way to capture it with an event listener?

```
$(document).on("model-modified", handler)
```